# Android facebook posting poll to wall

Tags: android, facebook

I tried the following code to post a question on my facebook wall but it fails. But posting question alone (without options) is working fine.

```
     mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
           try{
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("question", "My first Qusetion ?");
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
            try{
              options.put("Opt1",true);
              options.put("Opt2",false);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            params.putString("options",options.toString());
            String  response = facebook.request("me/questions",params,"POST");
        }catch(Exception e){}
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`, and make sure that the JSONArray's `.toString()` function makes an output string that looks like `["hiking", "parking"]` because that is how we expect the options parameter to be like. You can try it in the Graph API explorer to verify it works, I just did with a POST to `me/questions` with a `question` parameter and an `options` parameter with the value being above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check Your APP ID.
private static final String APP_ID = "Your APP ID";
private Facebook facebook;
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
restoreCredentials(facebook);

Call This Code on your button click
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("Question", "My First Question");
try { facebook.request("check/me");
String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
showToast("Blank response."); }
else {
showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
}
finish();
} catch (Exception e) {
showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
e.printStackTrace();
}
```